# Test a web application which has a callback page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-4.0

I can usually test my web application on my PC. (In "production" it's on a web hosting server.) But now I have a callback page (.ashx) and am not sure how to proceed - How do I have my application receive the callback? Is there some way to have the callback page redirect to my PC? Some way to have my PC receive callbacks and specify the callback address as my IP (I can chose any callback url I want.)?  Maybe some other way?

I don't need to actually attach it to the debugger, only to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

If your ASHX file is in an ASP.NET Web application or website, you can host it locally with IIS or visual studio and then call it with Fiddler (www.fiddler2.net)

Using fiddler you can make calls to your ASHX and pass any payload required.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into that now. (Though I would still rather have some direct way of doing it.)

Comment: There are some sophisticated techniques to accomplish what you are describing, but it is not a great idea to redirect production traffic for debugging.  If you are having issues in production you should consider improving the logging in your code. Also, if you prod environment supports remote debugging that is also an option.

Comment: Thanks. But this isn't production code. I can use the 3rd party site for testing as well. I just don't know how to get their "callback" and process it on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your network environment, but depending on how flexible it is, you could set up dyndns or a static domain so that your callbacks actually reach your PC.

I don't love it, but it's a logical solution. Then once you've got everything working properly, you update the domain in all of your call backs to point to production, and you should be ready to go.